# HtmlUnit issue with login popup

Tags: java, htmlunit

Been reading this forum for a while but just signed up, this is my first post, so kudos for the great job done here.

I am writing a program in Java with the purpose of using HtmlUnit to connect to one of the magazines I am a subscriber at, login and search for articles that interest me. Once I get that working it will send me an email but that's not relevant to my question.

I can't get the login to work:

- I read the page
- Find the login button and click it
- Capture the result in a new page, extract the form and supply username/password and finally
- click on login button

If you click on login, a popup comes up. But I can't seem to be able to capture the popup.

This is my code:

```
public void authenticate() throws MalformedURLException, IOException
{

    LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");      
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_9);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(false);

    webClient.addWebWindowListener(new WebWindowListener()
    {

          public void webWindowOpened(WebWindowEvent event)

          {
              System.out.println("a NEW window opened: " + event.getNewPage());
              windows.add(event.getWebWindow()); 

          }

        @Override
        public void webWindowClosed(WebWindowEvent event) {
            System.out.println("a window is CLOSED: " + event.getOldPage()); 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void webWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent event) {}

    });

    // Get the first page
    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("**");
    HtmlDivision div = (HtmlDivision) page1.getElementById("topContainer"); 

    HtmlAnchor anchor = (HtmlAnchor) div.getElementById("loginBtn1");       
    HtmlPage logPage = (HtmlPage) anchor.click();
    System.out.println("logPage is: "+logPage);

    if ( windows.size() > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("YIOUHOUU");
            HtmlPage popupPage = getPopupPage();
            System.out.println(popupPage.getTitleText());
    } 

    HtmlForm form = logPage.getFormByName("loginForm");
    System.out.println("Form: "+ form);

    HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("username");
    HtmlPasswordInput password = form.getInputByName("password");
    HtmlCheckBoxInput rememberPassword = form.getInputByName("remember");
    HtmlCheckBoxInput acceptTerms = logPage.getElementByName("acceptTerms");
    HtmlAnchor button = form.getElementById("loginButton");

    username.setValueAttribute("USER");
    password.setValueAttribute("RANDOM_PASS");
    rememberPassword.setChecked(true);
    acceptTerms.setChecked(true);

    System.out.println(form.toString());

    HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    System.out.println(page2.asText());
    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

I get the login page, get the form and supply the fields. All that is done, but when on the second page and click login nothing happens.

Even if you submit fields and click SUbmit nothing happens. I am looking at source of html page but can't figure out why, is it ajax or sth else in the background?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

For a popup login box, you can use the url to pass username and password.

If you are using this following line to get into that login page:

```
String url = "http://example.com";
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
```

Then change this link to following one and it should work:

```
String username = "YOUR USERNAME";
String password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
String url = "http://" + username + ":" + password + "@example.com";
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATE: Gave this up and solved this using Selenium and their WebDriver API which made this easy as pie. It seems that Htmlunit is not suited for this type of tasks and heed my advice and avoid it for similar purposes.